# Blazor WebAssembly 3.1 Target Framework is missing

Tags: blazor, .net-standard, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-client-side

I created a .NET Core Web API and class library with .NET Standard 3.1. But when I try to create Blazor WebAssembly with 3.1, it automatically creates a 2.1 version - as seen here:

[image]

This is my Blazor web and .NET Core 3.1 is not listed. I install the 3.1 version again but still not listing. I already have .NET Core 3.1 version on Web API and class library but I don't understand why I can not create Blazor 3.1.

But when can I create blazor server side application as 3.1 but I can't create web assembly as 3.1. Any idea would be great

Thanks

Comment: You're confusing the **.NET Core** version (which is currently at **3.1**), and the **.NETStandard** version which is currently in fact at **2.1**. Any library written against **.NETStandard 2.1** is in fact only compatible with **.NET Core** 3.1. See https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/10/dotnet-core-standard-difference/

Comment: Web Assembly must target .NET Standard 2.0. It uses Mono client-side, which is a different framework than .NET Core, and is only compatible with .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, .NET Standard 2.1 is now the correct version to use

Answer (score 4):

This is OK. This is the latest version of Blazor WebAssembly App: .NETStandard 2.1

A Blazor WebAssembly App, unlike Blazor Server App , runs under the Mono runtime. It is not .Net Core.

Just add the project and try it. Alas, it works ;)

Comment: please see .net 5.0 features for blazor => https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-8/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.NET 5` (a unified platform): `.NET 5.0.100-rc.1` is now available and supports Blazor client-side WebAssembly and Blazor server-side.

See this example: https://github.com/danroth27/BlazorNet5Samples

`.NET 5` takes `.NET Core` and the best of `Mono(.netstandard)` to create a single platform that you can use for all your modern .NET code.

See also this link about .NET 5: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/