# Cannot Migrate Blazor App to .Net 5 Due to System.Runtime Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have been working through an awesome tutorial within Udemy to learn more about Blazor (https://www.udemy.com/course/programming-in-blazor-aspnet-core/), but have hit a stumbling block that I'm not entirely sure what to do with.

**Short Version**

When upgrading to .Net 5 from .Net Standard 2.1, I end up with this error when trying to run this sample Blazor application as soon as it loads up (so it's not hitting any of my code): `System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000014 from typeref (expected class 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')` I see a similar problem with [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931707/blazor-wasm-system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-010000), but it didn't really give me much to go off of.

**Detailed Version**

With prior versions of .Net, you installed the latest, then Visual Studio picked that up, you switched projects and away you went - everything was seamless and just worked. With some of the newer stuff though, Microsoft's messaging has been extremely confusing and the problem I'm hitting now is inside that Udemy tutorial I need to utilize the `IJSObjectReference` interface to do something. When I first added that to the code, the type reference couldn't be resolved so a quick search pointed me to needing to move the project to .Net 5 by changing this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to this (because Visual Studio doesn't always show .Net 5 as an option):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Seemed simple enough, so I changed the Client Blazor project to this and tried to compile. That gives me this error: `Project BlazorMovies.Client is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project BlazorMovies.Client supports: net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)`. I figured okay, I'll bump Server to 5.0 next and then everything compiles fine, but as soon as I pull it up, I get this error: `System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000014 from typeref (expected class 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')`. Then I remembered not recalling if I'd installed .Net 5 yet, so I went to check and (via [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#:%7E:text=Detect%20.NET%20Framework%201.0%20through%204.0%20%20,REG_DWORD%20equals%201%20%203%20more%20rows%20)) I only have 4.8.03752 installed. I then did some searches to try and find the .Net installers and there were multiple (see [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)) - even the layout of the page is really overwhelming, with ~20 install links scattered throughout. I knew I needed at least x64, so I first installed the SDK since it said Visual Studio support and that went significantly faster than I expected (based on prior installs of .Net), but now VS is showing .Net 5 which seemed promising! I re-checked the registry though, and it still says 4.8.03752 and when I went to Add/Remove programs, .Net 5 doesn't show up like all the other versions. I next installed the Hosting Bundle which said it was successful, but the sample app still has the exact same error.

Any advice? I know Blazor is quite new, but with Microsoft's extremely confusing messaging between .Net Framework, .Net Standard, .Net Core and now a migration back into .Net 5 that seems to need multiple installers, I don't really know where to go next. That error is entirely generated from within the Web Assembly code according to the stack trace, so it doesn't appear to be anything related to what I'm doing. Here's a screenshot of everything Chrome shows me in the console: [image: Stack Trace]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To migrate Blazor Webassembly Application from `netstandard2.1` to `.NET 5`, you could refer the following steps:

1. [Install or update](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5003878) Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.8.0+, and install the [.NET 5 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5003878).
2. Change the Blazor Webassembly project setting.

   Create a Blazor Webassembly project (When create the application, [select .net core 3.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hepwo.png), then, the TargetFrameWork will be `.netstandard2.1`), Open the application .csproj file:

   - Update the SDK from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly`
   - Set the TargetFramework to `net5.0`
   - In case you have it, remove the package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build`.

   After updating, the .csproj file content as below:

   ```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly"> 
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework> 
      </PropertyGroup> 
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1" /> 
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0" />
      </ItemGroup> 
    </Project>
   ```
3. Update the Nuget dependencies version.

   The result like this:

   [image]

   Then, the final .csproj file content looks as below:

   ```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly"> 
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework> 
      </PropertyGroup> 
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.2" /> 
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup> 
    </Project>
   ```
4. Clean the entire solution, otherwise the build engine won’t be able to re-generate all the required files with the updated framework.

   Then running the application, the website works well.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up! It seemed to get me closer, but now I have 400 build errors that are all basically the same thing: `Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file "\obj\Debug\net5.0\compressed\_framework\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll.gz" because it was not found.` (tons of these, for various .Net 5.0 Microsoft assemblies, despite deleting the "obj" folder, cleaning the solution, etc.).

Comment: I also have another build error on the other sample project: `Error BLAZORSDK1001 The project references the ASP.NET Core shared framework, which is not supported by Blazor WebAssembly apps. Remove the framework reference if directly referenced, or the package reference that adds the framework reference.` For the life of me, I can't find what that reference is - I've tried everything I can think of to remove it, but no luck.

Comment: To keep things moving, I tried re-creating the project (it's just a sample, so not a big deal), but this time as .Net 5 instead and it all works! I'll just migrate my sample changes over to this - thanks for the help though! Definitely eye opening that it needed so much manual work to fix.

Comment: @ScottSalyer did you ever work out what the issue was here? I ran the manual process to (I have a Client, Server and Shared projects). VS seems to find no issue with linking the .Shared project to he Client project but I get the error you mention here?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn unfortunately, no. Setting up a brand new project is what solved it for me, but previously I was only playing with a sample so it was the quicker solution. Sorry I can't offer anything additional!

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the header node in the *.csproj too?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```