# target framework seems wrong after creating Blazor app in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, blazor

I wanted to create a blazor webassembly app in .NET Core 3.1, I've chosen this option when creating it. But target framework seems .Net Standart after creating the project.

I wanted to create a blazor webassembly app in .NET Core 3.1; and i created it like this:

[image]

But it creates the project as .Net Stanmdart 2.1, .Net Core is not shown even in drop down menu:

[image]

I am not facing this problem with other projects that are not blazor.

CanI not use .Net core in blazor anymore? What is the reason and how can I fix this?

Comment: I think this is as it should be. There was no 3.1 runtime for Wasm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor WebAssembly 3.1 Target Framework is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170445/blazor-webassembly-3-1-target-framework-is-missing)

Comment: More important: you shouldn't (want to) use 3.1 for a new project now.